# iBeacons issue: Did enter region triggers multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ibeacon

I'm working with a sample app for iBeacon region monitoring functionality. The Issue(not sure if it is) that I was unable to resolve is "didEnterRegion:" fires continuously for more than 2 times when I enter the region. This happens to send the local notification more than once or the times that this method fires when the app is in minimized mode.

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have multiple locationManager objects defined?  Apple's document states that if multiple locationManager objects share a delegate then the delegate will receive multiple notifications.

Comment: There is only one LocationManager object.

Answer (score 2):

It is common for a glitch in iOS to cause a didExitRegion event followed within a second by a didEnterRegion event. You can filter these out in your code by storing in an NSDate variable the time you last exited the region. When you get a didEnterRegion callback, you simply ignore it if the exit timestamp was within the last few secs.

If you are really getting these *continuously* as you say, something else is wrong that you may need to fix.  It is possible that your iBeacon is not transmitting at least once every three seconds.  This would cause constant exit/entry callbacks.